# My AddtoCart Method in my MVC ShoppingCart app is returning Null when receiving the product details from TescoLabsApi:

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

As I am getting the product information from the TescoLabs Api My method is returning null when I call the AddtoCart method:

My MakeRequest method below shows this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRrcd.png):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MakeRequest(string q)
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "api key ");

    var uri = string.Format("https://dev.tescolabs.com/grocery/products/?query={0}&offset={1}&limit={2}", q, 0, 100);

    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
    string body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = JObject.Parse(body);

    IList<JToken> results = result["uk"]["ghs"]["products"]["results"].Children().ToList();

    //// serialize JSON results into .NET objects
    IList<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    foreach (JToken r in results)
    {
        // JToken.ToObject is a helper method that uses JsonSerializer internally
        Product product = r.ToObject<Product>();
        products.Add(product);
    }
    return View(products);
```

I have the AddToCart Method:

```
public void AddToCart(Product Product)
{
    var cartItem = listDB.Carts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId && c.Id == Product.ID);
    if (cartItem == null)
    {
        cartItem = new Cart
        {
            Id = Product.ID,
            CartId = ShoppingCartId,
            Count = 1,
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now
        };
        listDB.Carts.Add(cartItem);
    }
    else {
        cartItem.Count++;
    }
    listDB.SaveChanges();

}
```

this is my ShoppingCartController with the ActionResult Method:

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(string name)
{
    var addedProduct = listDB.products.FirstOrDefault(product => product.Name == name);
    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
    cart.AddToCart(addedProduct);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

but for some reason when I click in the Add button the exception below shows:

```
System.Reflection.TargetException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232829
  Message=Non-static method requires a target.
  Source=mscorlib
```

the product information is returning null [runtime exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyEoZ.png)

How could I modify my `AddToCart` method to receive the product information from `TescoLabsApi` and then add to my cart?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be where it goes wrong.

```
var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
```

What is the value of the ShoppingCart reference - where is it defined?